# How to full-upgrade without interactive prompt for config file merge (e.g., /etc/ssh/sshd_config)?

Tags: apt

I am performing a full upgrade on the Raspberry Pi 4 B+ on the [2020-08-20-raspios-buster-arm64-lite.zip](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2020-08-24/2020-08-20-raspios-buster-arm64-lite.zip) image after I have modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to my liking.

I have tried setting the following:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local
Dpkg::Options {
  "--force-confdef";
  "--force-confold";
}
EOF
```

I have also specified `--allow-change-held-packages` in the command:

```
apt -y --allow-change-held-packages full-upgrade
```

Despite these settings, I get prompted with an interactive menu giving me options which include an option to keep the config file I have despite a newer one being available in the new package (this is the option I want).

How can I update my system non-interactively and always keep my config files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a semicolon. Here are the contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local on nodes where I need to keep the apt-get scripts that run outside of chef from freaking out over modified files:

```
quiet "1";
Dpkg::Options {"--force-confold";};
```